# Single RMI stub vs many

Tags: java, rmi

I did not find good answer to this so decided to post. What is the best strategy to use RMI, in terms of number of stubs?

a) one client stub used by many concurrent threads
b) stub per interaction(ie. each thread has its own stub)

Comment: It depends entirely on the scenario, there's no general answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

RMI stubs are thread-safe. There is no advantage to acquiring many copies of the same stub, and a considerable performance penalty.

In fact there is really no such thing as 'a number of stubs'. All stubs to the same remote object are logically and functionally equivalent. They even have the same hashcode, and are equal under `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to call metods on stub .So use single stub and  take care of shared resource on server side.